# libJPEG WinAPI Error

Tags: image, winapi, libjpeg

Procedure read JPEG file

```
void read_jpeg_file(char *szNamaFile)
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned char* raw_image;
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    unsigned long location = 0;

    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo ;

    errno_t err;
    FILE *infile;
    err = fopen_s(&infile, szNamaFile, "rb" );

    if (infile == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening jpeg file %s\n!", szNamaFile );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

    /* create decompressor */
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

    /* this makes the library read from infile */
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile );

    /* read jpeg header */
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

    /* decompress */
    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

    /*allocate memory */
    raw_image = (unsigned char*)malloc( cinfo.output_width*cinfo.output_height*cinfo.num_components );

    /* now actually read the jpeg into the raw buffer */
    row_pointer[0] = (unsigned char *)malloc( cinfo.output_width*cinfo.num_components );
    /* read scanlines */
    while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
        jpeg_read_scanlines( &cinfo, row_pointer, 1 );
        for(i = 0; i < cinfo.image_width*cinfo.num_components; i++) 
            raw_image[location++] = row_pointer[0][i];
    }  

    /* clean up */
    jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    fclose( infile );
    free( row_pointer[0] );
}
```

Procedure Open File Dialog

```
void OpenDialog(HWND hWnd) 
{
    OPENFILENAME    ofn     = {sizeof(ofn)};

    ofn.hwndOwner       = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter     = TEXT("File BMP (*.BMP)\0*.BMP\0File JPG (*.JPG)\0*.JPG\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex    = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFile       = szNamaFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0]    = '\0';
    ofn.lpstrTitle      = TEXT("Test ...");
    ofn.nMaxFile        = sizeof(szNamaFile);
    ofn.Flags           = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

  if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
  {
      read_jpeg_file(ofn.lpstrFile);
  }
}
```

WM_COMMAND

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        if(HIWORD(wParam) != BN_CLICKED)
            break;
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDB_LOAD:
                OpenDialog(hWnd);
                break;
        }
        break;
```

Image doesn't show,, how to fix it? maybe I should send a message to WM_PAINT?

Sorry if I ask many questions ,, because I am still a beginner

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Also, consider that you can open a BMP/GIF/JPEG/PNG/TIFF/Exif/WMF/EMF in XP using nothing other than the components of windows itself - there's no need for external libraries. You can do it with GDI+, using the `Gdiplus::Bitmap` class. After initializing GDI+, you can throw a WCHAR * and a BOOL at the constructor of a GdiPlus::Bitmap, before getting an HBITMAP from it with the `GetHBITMAP` member function. My comment is longer than the code required to perform the task for any/all of the image formats mentioned!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but I want to know how to use the library libjpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the first warning use `fopen_s` like this:

```
FILE *infile;
errno_t err = fopen_s(infile, szNamaFile, "rb");
if(0 == err)
{
    // Proceed with reading if file is opened properly
    ...
}
```

To fix the second warning, replace `int` with `size_t`:

```
size_t i;
for( i = 0; i < cinfo.image_width * cinfo.num_components; i++)
```

Comment: thx i already fix the error,, but why the picture does not appear ?

Comment: @RyuAndyaPratama There is no way for me to know that, you did not post any code that deals with drawing of the image. Btw, I agree with the suggestion made by @enhzflep in comment section. If you do not have some specific reason to use libJPEG-Turbo, it would be a lot easier to use `Gdiplus::Bitmap` class. That way, you can easily read and draw the image and support several formats at once.

Comment: The code you have posted in your deals with opening a dialog which is used to chose an image file on the disk. As far as drawing and image goes, the only way I can remember is to create a `Gdiplus::Bitmap` object using pixel data in `raw_image` and then draw it using `Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage` when handling `WM_PAINT` message of your window. This conversion to `Bitmap` is a fairly complex task, please refer to MSDN for documentation on how to use this classes.